# SCADA LTS - HTTP Status 404

Tags: docker, tomcat, catalina, scadalts

After starting a SCADA LTS Docker container as suggested on https://github.com/SCADA-LTS/Scada-LTS with the following command:

`docker run -it -e DOCKER_HOST_IP=`docker-machine ip`-p 81:8080 scadalts/scadalts /root/start.sh`

...The container works well for some time and then suddenly a "HTTP Status 404" error is shown, like the following:

http://[IP]/ScadaBR/

> HTTP Status 404 - /ScadaBR/
>
> type Status report
>
> message /ScadaBR/
>
> description The requested resource is not available.
>   Apache Tomcat/7.0.85

Where [IP] is the default Docker IP address and port, most of the times is localhost:81.

Any idea how to solve it?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**

After some time running the MySQLservice dies. Is necessary to restart it manually with this:

```
docker exec scada service mysql restart
docker exec scada killall tail
```

---

**DETAILED REPORT**

When the error is shown, you can check if all the services are running on the container (in this case named 'scada'):

```
>docker exec scada ps -A
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
    1 ?        00:00:00 start.sh
  790 ?        01:00:22 java
  791 ?        00:01:27 tail
  858 ?        00:00:00 ps
```

As can be seen, no MySQL service is running. This explains why Tomcat is running but SCADA-LTS don't.

You can restart MySQL service inside the container with:

```
docker exec scada service mysql restart
```

After that SCADA-LTS is still down and you have to restart tomcat which can be done in this way:

```
docker exec scada killall tail
```

After a minute or less, all the services are running:

```
>docker exec scada ps -A
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
    1 ?        00:00:00 start.sh
   43 ?        00:00:00 mysqld_safe
  398 ?        00:00:00 mysqld
  481 ?        00:00:31 java
  482 ?        00:00:00 sleep
  618 ?        00:00:00 ps
```

Now SCADA-LTS is running!